# What's the difference of different ways of binding data

Tags: d3.js

From this tutorial: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234 , I read

```
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d; });
```

And sometimes I read from other tutorials like the following and it works for their use case:

```
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data);
```

The tutorial won't work with the second way by failing to trigger enter & exit. So what's the difference of the two ways, conceptually?

Comment: Are you aware, that D3's API is very well documented? The section about [`selection.data()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) provides all the details answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fine manual on [`selection.data`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

> `selection.data([values[, key]])`
>
> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in values is
>   assigned to the first element in the current selection, the second
>   datum to the second selected element, and so on.
>
> [...]
>
> A key function key([ d [, i ]]) may be specified to control how data
>   is joined to elements (this replaces the default by-index behavior).
>   The key function returns a string which is used to join a datum with
>   its corresponding element, based on the previously-bound data.

In your example, `function(d) { return d; }` specifies that the key is the letter used. Later calls will be able to determine what node represents what letter and thus determine the enter and exit selections.

Without this key, you don't have any data to match nodes between calls besides the order in which you passed the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help to D3 newbie and also thanks for reminders from others that I shall dig in the manual first :)